# why my list model show this error : type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have try to add List in my model and add data to my homepage but I have this error only when I add `" suite=widget.todo.suite;` in the initstate :

```
  suite=widget.todo.suite;  => type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

If I use an other data model as "id" who is a string or "isDone" who is a bool I have no error. But my "suite" data have error
I don't understand.

```
-------------------homepage--------------

class Add_suite extends StatefulWidget {
  final Todo todo;
  const Add_suite({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Add_suiteState createState() => _Add_suiteState();
}

class _Add_suiteState extends State<Add_suite> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String title;
  String description;
  List<String>  suite =[""];
  List<String> stringList = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete(() {
      print("completed");
      setState(() {});
    });
 
    suite=widget.todo.suite;
    title = widget.todo.title;
    description = widget.todo.description;

  }

...
 }

-------------------model--------------

class Todo {
  DateTime date;
  String title;
  String id;
  String description;
  List  suite;
  bool isDone;

  Todo({
    @required this.date,
    @required this.title,
    this.description = '',
    this.suite,
    this.id,
    this.isDone = false,

  });

  static Todo fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Todo(
        date: Utils.toDateTime(json['createdTime']),
        title: json['title'],
        description: json['description'],
        suite: json['suite'],
        id: json['id'],
        isDone: json['isDone'],

  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'date': Utils.fromDateTimeToJson(date),
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'suite': suite,
        'id': id,
        'isDone': isDone,

  };
}
```

---

Edit: if I change list suite par list suite

my Streambuilder return error. If I use list I have no error on streambuilder but an other error with dynamic type

```
StreamBuilder<List<Todo>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('first_stories')
            .orderBy("date", descending: true)
            .snapshots()
            .transform(Utils.transformer(Todo.fromJson)),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return buildText('Erreur');
              } else {
                final todos = snapshot.data;

                final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context);
                provider.setTodos(todos);

                return
                    TodoListWidget();


              }
          }
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Todo` class, you need to specify your `List` type :

`List<String> suite;`

---

By default, if you not specify type, it's `dynamic` type :

`List suite;` is egal to `List<dynamic> suite;`

---

If you can't specify a type in `Todo` class, you can cast your dynamic `List` when you set it in `suite` :

`suite = widget.todo.suite as List<String>;`

### EDIT

You also have to convert your data in `fromJson` function. Try this :

`suite: List<String>.from(json['suite']),`

Comment: Thank you I change suite = widget.todo.suite as List<String> but  I have type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast. I changed also List<String> suite; but my streambuilder return error, I edit my post with the streambuilder

Comment: What kind of data do you have in `widget.todo.suite` ? A list of String?

Comment: Yes it's a list of String that I send to firebase and try to read/convert to be display

Comment: You also need to update your `fromJson` function. I update my answer.